# How to Add Custom Field (Not an Attribute) in Magento Add/Edit Product Price Tab?

Tags: price

I want to add new custom field, it is not an attribute, in Magento add/edit product price tab, but I didn't found the template file for it.

I found the template file for categories tab in `app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/catalog/product/edit/categories.phtml`

So how does Magento generating the price tab? And how to add new custom field into it?

Answer (score 2):

Don't Change the code Directly in core Files.

1) First you have to override your admin catalog block using your custom module
2) override the _prepareForm() Form method and you can write the

```
$fieldset->addField('new_text_field', 'text', array(
            'name'=>'new_text_field',
            'class'=>'requried-entry',
            'label'=> Mage::helper('catalog')->__('New Text Field'),
            'title'=> Mage::helper('catalog')->__('New Text Field'),
    ));
```

3) This is the actual way of clean Code in Magento without touching Core Files.

Comment: HI Keyur can you please tell me how can i add new field in group price section like date to and date from . thanks

Comment: I have to check for that

Comment: OK please guide me if you have some idea , so that i can add new fields and store there information in ndatabase

Answer (score 0):

location of class >> app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Catalog/Product/Edit/Tab/Attributes.php

Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Edit_Tab_Attributes,inside this class you can add a new field of price tab. following code as an example..

```
protected function _prepareForm()
    {
........

$fieldset->addField('new_text_field', 'text', array(
                'name'=>'new_text_field',
                'class'=>'requried-entry',
                'label'=> Mage::helper('catalog')->__('New Text Field'),
                'title'=> Mage::helper('catalog')->__('New Text Field'),
        ));
```

Happy coding!